# Connecting ESP to USB Port

Tags: esp32, usb

I have a question about connection from board ESP to  USB Port. I can not connect to this port although I setup driver.
I use ESP-WROVER-KI. Run on MacOS 10.14

```
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py", line 2959, in <module>
    _main()
  File "/Users/apple/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py", line 2952, in _main
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py", line 2652, in main
    esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
  File "/Users/apple/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py", line 222, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/serial/__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

Could anyone with experience connecting to USB port tell me the reason why?

Comment: what does the error message tell you?

Comment: @jsotola could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0.
Because I can't establish serial connection with ESP32.

Comment: Although I try to install driver FTDI, it is not work.

Comment: The important part seems to be `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'`

Comment: @hardillb think it happened because I can not establish connection between EST to USB port

Comment: I have a question, when we list all device by "ls /dev/tty*"
Then ttyUSB0 is not exist in list. Why ?
How can I create ttyUSB0

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/ttyUSB0` is how Linux refers to USB Serial ports.

MacOS uses `/dev/tty.usbserial` with the FTDI driver

Comment: When I list all device connect to my laptop. I dont see any tty.usbserial.
In bellow introduction, They said that list by "ls /dev/cu.*"
But I dont see any usb serial when I do that. This driver is false ?

Comment: @TrungLM what about `ls /dev/tty*`